# Поиск при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, python-3.5

Как найти в строке слова, у которых последняя буква гласная, а предпоследняя согласная при помощи регулярных выражений?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = 'Как найти в строке слова, у которых последняя буква гласная, а предпоследняя согласная при помощи регулярных выражений?'

vowels = 'аоиеёэыуюя'
consonants = 'бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщьъ'
pattern = r'\b[{0}{1}]+[{0}][{1}]\b'.format(consonants, vowels)

words = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(words)  # ['найти', 'строке', 'слова', 'буква', 'при', 'помощи']
```

Значение в `pattern`:

```
\b[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщьъаоиеёэыуюя]+[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщьъ][аоиеёэыуюя]\b
```